# Different markup based on foreach output

Tags: php, foreach, checkboxlist

I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days but no luck so far unfortunately. I want to sort appointments based on category/type and put them in seperate divs. For example:

My foreach loop generates an input checkbox for each available appointment of type '**normal**' and '**special**'.

Now I can get a list of ALL appointments with:

```
print $apptOutput;
```

This outputs a list of appointments that users can select by using checkboxes:

- 30-08-16 11:05 Special
- 31-08-16 09:55 Special
- 31-08-16 20:05 Normal
- 01-09-16 20:00 Normal
- 02-09-16 20:05 Normal

What I'm trying to do is giving each category a different div so the output is seperated. For example, I want it to be this:

```
<div id="normal">
  <label for="normal">Normal</label>
    <?php print $apptOutput; ?>
</div>
```

And for Special:

```
<div id="special">
  <label for="special">Special</label>
     <?php print $apptOutput; ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't easily solve the problem at the stage that you have `$appOutput` if it's already generated HTML. You need to solve it at the point that you're generating `$appOutput`, because then it's easier to identify which things are *Special* and which are *Normal*.

Let's say you get this data from a database. At the point that you're traversing the result set from your database, you can place each item in a distinct array key based this criteria of *Special* and *Normal*, making it easier to generate the output of each type of item into its own div.

```
$data = [
    "Special" => [],
    "Normal"  => [],
];
// $resultSet being your database result set or however you get the data
foreach($resulSet as $result) {
    if ($result["type"] == "Special") {
        $data["Normal"][] = $result;
    } elseif ($result["type"] == "Normal") {
        $data["Special"][] = $result;
    }
}
```

Now in your template you can more easily generate the result.

```
<div id="normal">
    <?php foreach($data["Nomral"] as $item) { ?>
        <label for="normal"><?=$item['name']?></label>
        <input type="checkbox" ...>
    <?php } ?>
</div>

<div id="special">
    <?php foreach($data["Special"] as $item) { ?>
        <label for="normal"><?=$item['name']?></label>
        <input type="checkbox" ...>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Although, the foreach wasn't even necessary in my template file. Thank you.